# What equipment do I need to film downwards over a table?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, document-reproduction

I would like to be able to film what I'm writing and drawing on a table, inside a light cube. I just want to be able to sit at my table and have the camera above it pointing downwards.

I would have two requirements: that the camera is firmly fixed, it must really not move when I'm writing, but at the same time that the equipment is easy to unmount and transport.

I'm attaching two pictures of the equipment of the guy from minutephysics, because I'd like to get the same configuration basically, except I don't find his "tripod" anywhere on the internet! I'm either really bad at searching, or they used something that was not made for photography at first.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/capture1ujp.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/capture2kf.png/

So do you know what this kind of "tripod" is called, and where I can find it? Or do you have another solution to film inside a light cube above a table with the above requirements?

Budget $300-400 max if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a document camera set up. You can see some examples at [this link](https://www.schooloutfitters.com/catalog/default/cPath/CAT1_CAT366?kw_cid=digital%20document%20camera&sc_cid=digital%20document%20camera%7CPPCsearch%7Cb%7C14980920257%7CSOG1001512%7C%28Document%29%20Document%20Camera%7CAv%20equipment:%20document%20cameras%7CGoogle%7C).

Here's some more info on **copy stands**:

> NOTE: A **copy stand** is a device used to copy images and/or text with a camera. 
>   The stand consists of a board onto which the media is
>   placed and a camera mount above it, usually with an adjustable height.
>   Light is provided by either sunlight or bright lamps mounted on either
>   side of the media at forty-five degree angles. This provides uniform
>   lighting and reduces specular reflection, keeping glare low. Copy
>   stands can be used for reprography (that is, to copy documents). To do
>   so, the camera is mounted onto the stand, usually with a standard 1/4"
>   tripod-mount screw, pointing the lens down at the base, where you
>   would place the document to be copied.
>
> You can purchase copy stands at any major photo store or from dozens
>   of online merchants. For examples of various copy stands available,
>   look at http://www.google.com/products?q=copy+stand&aq=f
>   - See more at: http://blog.eogn.com/eastmans_online_genealogy/2010/02/-tether-your-camera-to-shoot-docs-and-pics.html#sthash.AUU8S0L0.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

I think Jim's answer is what you're looking for.  However you could also research tripods with *boom arms* or with and articulating centre post.  They might be more generally useful, but probably not compact enough to fit inside your light tent like a copy stand of some kind.

For example:

[http://www.amazon.com/Manfrotto-196B-2-2-Section-Articulated-Bracket/dp/B000OPWSYM/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1361916697&sr=8-5&keywords=tripod+boom+arm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OPWSYM)

[http://www.amazon.com/Vanguard-Alta-Pro-264AT-Multi-Angle/dp/B003BQ0TFQ/ref=pd_sim_sbs_e_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BQ0TFQ)

Comment: Interesting, I'll think about it. Indeed I'll either have to make a hole in my light tent or don't use a light tent and just use lights on both sides instead.

Answer (score 0):

two stands with a holding up a horizontal pole. Attach camera with a Manfrotto Superclamp with a spiggot that can screw into the thread at the base of your camera.
http://www.manfrotto.com/photo-clamps-super-clamps